# Is there an accepted way of indicating user action vs computed action on a flowchart?

Tags: workflow, flowcharts, communication

We've found that using flowcharts to help communicate between technical and non-technical teams to be incredibly helpful. The different shapes have different meanings and these are generally accepted and well documented (e.g. a diamond shape indicates a "decision"). However, one thing we haven't been sure or consistent on is how to indicate what is a user action and what is a computed action.

For example, in the same flowchart some decisions will be computed decisions, like "is the user logged in?" and some decisions will be user-input decisions, such as "was this article helpful?".

So is there a generally accepted way of differentiating these types of actions? If not, what do you do?

Comment: Currently I'm using a background and/or border colour to differentiate between user and computed actions.

Comment: As it's said above, you can use a swimlane diagram to show who does what in a process.

Answer (score 2):

You could show the user in the flowchart, like this:

[image]

If you use swimming lanes, it's quite common to have a lane for (a certain class of) user:

[image]

Comment: I like this idea, not seen it before. I don't think it's the complete solution for us as I think some of our more complex flows would probably become extremely difficult to read if things kept flying way off to the left and back again, but for the simpler flows I can definitely see it helping, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no accepted way. Like all charts and maps, include a legend defining what is what. It will clear up any assumptions and give you flexibility in deciding how to best represent what you are trying to communicate.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Of course, we absolutely do this already. However we will also do our best to be consistent, minimising the need for legends - that's why we're agreeing a standard internally, and checking if there is already an accepted standard before agreeing our own seemed wise.